# Full Width template for Wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I added a full width template page to a Wordpress site for use on one page: http://pjstagingdecorating.com/portfolio-testing2/#DTprettyPhoto

I added a new PHP file as well as CSS to my stylesheet.  The template does appear as an option BUT the content is not appearing across the full width of the page.  PHP and CSS below.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Full Width
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that other
 * 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <header class="entry-header full-width">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
                        <div class="entry-thumbnail">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if (is_front_page()) : ?>
<?php else : ?>
<h1 class="entry-title full-width"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                    <div class="entry-content full-width">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentythirteen' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                    <footer class="entry-meta">
                        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentythirteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
                </article><!-- #post -->

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And the CSS:

```
.full-width {
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    height: auto;
    padding-right: 1em !important;
}
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: I added `width:100%!important;` to the .full-width class and added the full-width class to #primary and #content in the PHP.  Still doesn't work.  Thanks!

 `<div id="primary" class="content-area full-width">
  <div id="content" class="site-content full-width" role="main">`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to ur css file:

```
.page-template-fullwidth .div#primary, .page-template-fullwidth .hentry {max-width:100%!important;}
```

It is recommended to create a [Child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to modify a Wordpress theme or your changes will be reset while you update your theme.
Here is a guide you can follow to create child theme:
http://variablez.com/wordpress/how-to-create-a-wordpress-child-theme

Comment: Thanks @Sparrow.  That didn't work, unfortunately.  I also tried applying your code to all the containers of these divs in the browser and nothing worked.  It seems to still be saving space for a sidebar.

Comment: R u using cloudflare? then turn on "Development Mode" Delete you browser cache. I used "inspect element" and it worked fine! And it seems u changed your theme. If u changed your theme then better close this question.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't change the theme.   It's still Twenty Thirteen.  I am using Chrome Inspect Element.

Comment: delete the class `.full-width` line 645, Add a class to full width child contents, `.page-template-fullwidth .sidebar .entry-header {max-width:100%!important;}` here is screenshot: http://imgur.com/FzvXtI2